# Did Soran succeed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, star-trek-generations

According to the canon movie *Star Trek Generations*, the Nexus is an extra-dimensional realm in which time and space have no meaning. The main antagonist of the film, Tolian Soran, wants to enter the Nexus so he could be reunited with his deceased family. His plan

> succeeds initially, but using the Nexus, Captain Picard stops him, leading to Soran's death.

However, if time is irrelevant in the Nexus, and Soran

> succeeded in one version of the plan,

does that mean that he is technically in the Nexus with a version of his deceased family?

Comment: Picard, Kirk, and Soran never escaped from the Nexus. They are still there. Everything after they entered is a Nexus happy dream.

Comment: I would hardly call Nemesis a happy dream.

Answer (score 5):

We can't know for certain. As time has no meaning in the Nexus, it is impossible to know whether the change to the timeline is reflected in Soran's experience.

The best analogue we have is [Guinan](https://youtu.be/Hkk-IYaXlVQ?t=242). Guinan, in entering and being pulled from the Nexus, left an echo of herself behind. By calling herself an echo, the vestige of Guinan left in the Nexus indicated that she was not a complete version of herself.

The question, to which we don't have an answer, is whether being pulled from the Nexus by transporter beam or a change in the timeline makes any difference.

Comment: Further, it may have been Guinan's continued existence outside of the Nexus which caused her presence inside of it to be incomplete; Soren's subsequent death may have consolidated him into the Nexus. Clearly, he himself wouldn't have believed in that possibility: had he been able to return to the Nexus simply by dying, he could have saved himself the considerable difficulty of hiring dodgy Klingons, slaughtering Romulans, blowing up a star, and so forth.